# What is the optimal way to play the remade Evelynn in the jungle?

Tags: league-of-legends

After the remake Eve has become much stronger in the jungle. Her base stats have improved and she has a much faster clearing time. Her Q can hit all mobs in the camps and her E helps trigger slots of Wiggle procs.

She has also become quite a potent roamer. Her passive means she avoids normal ward vision (but not vision wards) so she can gank over extended lanes pretty well, although mid lane ganks aren't very easy for her pre level 6.

Eve can also counter jungle very well, depending on the enemy jungler. She is not strong at dueling so you need to be careful.

1. Is Eve better as AD or AP when playing jungle?
2. Early-mid game, is it better to focus on ganking, counter jungling, or just normal
   jungling as she clears camps so fast?

Comment: Might want to edit the question now that remake is done.

Comment: And now the question has changed again due to the jungler remake. Current Meta as of 12/19 is she is a mid that ganks often.

Comment: Yea you are right... not sure how to manage my league questions, because they are constantly going out of date now!

Answer (score 2):

Let me stop you in your tracks mate :)! The thing about eve is that she is squishy and is played poorly very often and is easy to mess up. People misunderstand her for good reasons because she rarely shines and ends up feeding.

I have had success with her jungling by how she comes out of stealth and has the slow along with her e which shreds armor. Her ult allows her to gain health after a kill and move super fast. That is a perfect jungler description: a champ who can gank well and have some way to slow to have the laning champion(s) catch up.

I have had some success laning by being aggressive early (know your limits however) and then farming up while they stay back, some teams have eve roaming nonstop and a jungler on the side, while having only 1 champ in each lane.

It is true though she isn't really played in tournaments, but I have seen her in the high elos (2000 range) and those players know how to play her well!

Answer (score 2):

I find Jungle Eve to be much more effective in ranked than Mid lane Eve. As jungler she has the roam potential she was basically designed for. The best way I've found to play Eve is this (Remade Eve with the S3 item and jungle remake, **TL;DR version at the bottom**):

> I use my standard "AP Jungle" masteries and might be unusual I admit at 16-14-0.

Offensive I take the increased monster damage in Butcher and the 2% CDR in Sorcery. The rest of the 12 points go towards all AP masteries on the right side and Havoc

For Defensive I take the improves smite in Summoner's resolve. 4 points in durability and 2 in perserverance. 3 points total for Tough Skin and Bladed armor. Then the last 4 points all in Hardiness And Veteran's Scars for better sustainability in the starting jungle

> The runes I use are NOT optimal Jungle runes but this is what I have for reference.

Scaling AP Marks

Flat Armor Seals

Flat AP Glyphs

Flat AP Quints

Totals: 25.6 Flat AP, 16.82 AP @ lvl 18, 12.7 Flat Armor.

> This is my typical Jungle route for Eve specifically:

-Start hunter's machete + 5 pots. Get Q first

-Go to wolves and pound Q and AA the big wolf down first.

-Have mid-lane damage blue golem to start the leash. I like to let top lane tank it for a few hits while I stand back hitting it with Q.

-Once top lane lane leaves Smite blue and take out the small lizards. You should level up and take E here. Might want to take a pot as well now on the way to Wraiths.

-Make sure you go invis on your way to Wraiths so you get some mana back also.

-Q as you walk up to the wraiths and E the big one. Continue with Q and AA until dead.

-Same with smaller golems. Q to start and E when you get close. Continue Q and AA's. Use a pot or two here also before taking on Red.

-If you level here you can either take second point in Q if you want to continue jungling or W if you want to gank (which is what I recommend doing).

-Go invis for a bit before taking on Red buff to get some mana and have smite come off CD.

-Open with E on the Lizard Elder and pound Q again until dead.

-Gank a lane if someone is pushed (and you have quite a bit of health left ~350 at least or another pot left) or go back to base.

(Just a note: I prefer repeated ganks afer I go to base over continually farming the jungle. Though if the enemy is not pushed far or your team is winning their lane for the most part, Jungling may be your only option. Also, after the first blue, you don't have as much of a need for it as long as you know how to keep up your mana with your passive. Give blue to Mid whenever possible)

> Another effective but situational/optional route is:

-start at opponent's red buff (assuming the enemy jungler will for sure start at their blue).

-Take red with help of your mid or top lane. You should level up here and take E.

-Wait in tri-bush by top lane and gank ASAP for an almost guaranteed kill against most top laners

-Go back to base and continue with standard route above.

(Use mainly if you fear top lane will be at a disadvantage due to counter-picking or they face the rare duo top lane)

> Good Start Items:

Hunter's machete > spirit stone > sell later when you need an inventory space

Boots > Boots of mobility

> Items I try to get every game:

Haunting Guise > Liandry's Torment

Sheen > Lich Bane

Hextech Revolver > Hextech Gunblade

> Items for more defenses

Negatron Cloak > Abyssal Scepter

Chainmail > Zhonya's Hourglass

Giant's Belt > Rylai's Crystal Scepter

Catalyst The Protector > Rod of Ages

> Items for the fed Eve

Needlessly Large Rod > Rabbadon's Deathcap or DeathFire Grasp (Still useful after nerfs but no longer A must buy.)

Blasting Wand > Void Staff

> Other Items that may do well but I have not tried myself yet

Tear of the Goddess > Archangel's Staff > Seraph's Embrace (With max bonus Mana)

Stinger > Nashor's Tooth

Will of the Ancients (instead of Hextech Gunblade)

Blasting Wand > Guinsoo's Rageblade

> When Ganking...

Stay Invisible as you approach the enemy. You don't need to stay in the bush like other jungler's because of the invisibility. Open up with E and Repeated Q's. Don't use W unless they start to get away from you or flash away. I don't use my ult unless I need the extra damage. Best used when you first engage for the slow.

> In teamfights...

To start off a teamfight I like to hit as many people as posible with my ulti. After, you can either use your shield to absorb damage while you E > Q their carry to death, or back off for a bit and wait till the enemy uses more of their abilities.

If you stay, try to E their Highest damage dealer as often as possible. Also Mash Q trying to hit as many as possible

If you get caught you can sprint out with W pretty quickly and get out of slows as well.

If you back off after using your ult, I try to get between the enemy and their base to pick off anyone who gets away with low health.

That's the way I like to play her and am generally incredibly successful with it.

> TL;DR

Runes: Flat AP quint and blue. Flat armor yellow. Scaling AP red.

Masteries: 16-14-0 with AP boosts in offensive. Minion damage reduction in defense along with armor and health / health regen.

Route: wolves, blue, wraiths, small golems, red, gank or go base

Items: Start Hunter's + 5 pots, upgrade to Spirit Stone (sell later), Boots of Mobility Lich Bane, Liandry's Torment, Hextech Gunblade, Deathfire Grasp, Rabbadon's Deathcap.

Your combo is E > Q > Q > Q > Q > enemy is dead. Throw in W if they try to escape your wrath. If they are too stubborn to die or too fast for your team (not you, your too fast for anyone. Even *Teemo*), show em your ult and proceed to kill.

I think that's everything you need to know and be successful with the Jungle-is-Superior-to-Laning Evelynn.

Answer (score 1):

She doesn't really fit into the current meta, as far as I can see. Anything she *could* do, someone else can do better.

Answer (score 1):

Nowhere. She was intentionally weakened to the point of uselessness by Riot pending the still-unfinished stealth remake. Prior to having her back broken by Riot, she was a monster who would run rampant over every game she was in. Just avoid playing her until the remake is complete.

Answer (score 1):

Thankfully, the new jungle is so easy that every champ can do it easily.  Eve is an annoyance when played mediocre which is what you tend to see from those that play Eve.  For the ones who know how to play Eve, she is a menace and for the ones that don't know how to play Eve, she is a feeder.  Jungling and counterjungling with Evelynn works best in my opinion, her stealth allows her to move pretty freely on the map, and it is so easy to sneak behind their jungler stealthed and use your burst to smite steal anything they do as most junglers are in the habit of autoattacking creeps then smiting, so if you use an ability with auto-attack and smite you can easily smite steal from them.  After securing the buff, depending on the jungler, you can even land a quick kill to the jungler, especially with ignite.  If their team tries to react to the counterjungle, you have the stealth that lets you walk away freely.  Most important thing is you need to use that advantage to get an early oracles and make sure they can't use sight wards to stop you.

Eve ganks with red buff are devastating as the slows stack and like other junglers, if your lane can provide some CC it will result in a definite kill.  Eve's pressure in ganks is only rivalled by Twitch and Shaco for the early game, so you automatically force every lane to play passively, since Eve can be anywhere.  In the hands of good teammates, you will automatically let them have the advantage.  The enemy team may counter this by buying pink wards and put it in the lane.  Now you force them to spend 125 gold every 3 minutes for a ward position they normally would never do since it offers very little purpose before any towers are down.  Also once you have oracles, you can get your lane to push and give yourself an extra 25 gold.

Answer (score 0):

Eve can be good as a hybrid carry actually.  Its because she can use stealth and slow enemies when hitting from it, she can pick up last hits, and get fed easily.  At the same time, she is squishy, and dies easily till fed.  However, once you get fed, there is no hope left for your enemies, because she starts dishing out too much damage.  A hybrid will have over 200 AD and over 400AP, along with spell vamp and lifesteal.  Add in that her Ult's passive heals her a good amount after a kill or assist, and it comes off of cooldown as well, she can dive under a turret for a kill, and as long as she isn't ganked when coming out from under it, she got a free kill, since the turret damage is healed by the passive.  Her farming ability is strong in lane, thanks to her passive and hate spikes, which is fun to get cooldown for, and spam ever .49 seconds.  lol  No need, but fun as hell.  Her abilities are well balanced, since her old stun (I was not playing LOL during that time) was OP.  Stun with high damage output from stealth is outrageous.  It was bound to be nerfed from the sound of it.