# What roles can Evelynn fulfill?

Tags: league-of-legends

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does one play Evelynn effectively in the laning phase on Summoners Rift?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/15981/how-does-one-play-evelynn-effectively-in-the-laning-phase-on-summoners-rift)

Evelynn can not:

- jungle
- be supported by a support in the bottom lane
- be a support
- be top lane
- be middle lane

Where does she actually belong?