# How do you make Evelynn work?

Tags: league-of-legends

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does one play Evelynn effectively in the laning phase on Summoners Rift?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/15981/how-does-one-play-evelynn-effectively-in-the-laning-phase-on-summoners-rift)

Is there a way to play Eve effectively since they removed her stun?  Laning seems to be impossible, she doesn't seem to be able to 1v1 anyone, her jungle is very slow/counterable, and when I gank someone with an ally, I always feel like for stealth shaco does more damage with more cc + slow, and any other hero with a slow would bring more utility/damage.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

All you could hope for is a competent lane mate to help you finish off the gank. Ever since they nerfed Evelynn so her stun became a slow, shes really dependant on someone with a hard cc to help make the gank successful.

I would say that you can try to run exhaust on her to help make her ganks more potent like Shyvana, but then she would have no escape except for her invisibility, and you cant always rely on that to work. In which case Flash is still exceptional and almost necessary.

I'm almost positive that until they do something with stealth and rework her, jungle is the only way to even think about playing Evelynn.